# How to show the list of recently visited web pages as chrome does

Tags: c#, asp.net, thumbnails

I would like to display the list of recently accessed/visited web pages just as google chrome shows. I want to achieve this using C# and asp.net.

I am working on a site where the user can see the list of pages that they have visited, I tried using iframe but that does not work as per expectation. I am looking for a clean and intuitive interface something like google chrome.

I would like to provide a thumbnail view of the recently visited pages.

To keep my question simple, I want to display a list of urls as thumbnails, just as chrome does

Comment: What is your question. Get the history or better way to display them?

Comment: do you just want to show pages visited in your site or the pages visited by the user in his browser...

Comment: pages visited by the user in my website

Answer (score 3):

Note that Chrome can do it easy, as they get to render the page and can take a bitmap snapshot of it easily to show for the thumbnails. (These are not live websites in there)

If you want to do the same thing, you have to render the website offscreen and take a snapshot to show to the user.

If you want to actually show a live website - now that's another story. There are a lot of sites that don't like being shown in the context of another website (for whatever reasons - security, marketing and so on) and will employ any tricks (including legal) to make sure this does not happen.

Comment: I just want to show the list of pages thats visited by the user in my website, so lets say user has visted page1.aspx and page2.aspx, I would like to show thumbnail view of these two pages

Comment: Yes. As I said, you can do this two ways - either by taking a bitmap snapshot of the page or by showing a live page (as an iFrame).

Answer (score 0):

Pages only visited within your own app?

There are several components that will alow for that using their api. For example:
http://www.tonec.com/products/wssh/index.html

You can just take a snapshot after the DOM for tha page is completely generated and save the output using the tool on peruser basis.

Now, if you want something more generic that works for any web site, you'd probably want to go with a web browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a possible solution, although I've not tried it personally:

- Keep a record of all the pages that a user visits (e.g. in a database)
- When the user visits a landing page on your site, you could  call the `WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap` function to render a bitmap of each page they have visited recently.

**Please note: this is just a theory, I'm not saying it will work! ;)**

This link might help you get started:

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-generate-webpage-thumbmail-screenshot-image.aspx